# Cannot load assets on live server using the mix helper function

Tags: laravel, cross-compiling, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I am trying to run my application via a tunnel service (https://localtunnel.github.io/www/), but it sets the relative path to local which makes it so that my assets can't get loaded.

What I have tried:

- changing the mix helper to the assets helper -> works, but makes me unable to use the npm hot reload function. I would like to make use of this.

My blade file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
        <title>Laravel Vue Ecommerce</title>
        <link href=" {{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <app></app>
        </div>
        <script src="{{ mix('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps()
```

The errors:

```
GET https://localhost:8080/css/app.css net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
tame-dog-60.loca.lt/:16 

GET https://localhost:8080/js/bootstrap.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
tame-dog-60.loca.lt/:17 

GET https://localhost:8080/js/app.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Comment: try {{ url(mix('js/app.js')) }}

Comment: also try to update APP_URL in env or app.php

Comment: I have to dive deeper into the tunnel service first I think. I will get back to you.